# SQL query where value smaller than number

Tags: php, sql

I need to select from database banks which have the minimum <= 50 and than show the names of the banks and their tariffs. I did it like this, but it doesn't work.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list1 WHERE minimum <= 50]");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['bank_name'] . " - " . $row['Tarif'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list1 WHERE minimum <= 50]");
                                                              ^---typo
```

If you had the following construct, you'd have gotten the error message:

```
$result = mysql_query(yada yada) or die(mysql_error());
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```